# How to building and running apjsua sample application

Tags: android

I wanted to try PJSIP on an Android AVD.
I performed the following steps :

Now, the next step says : 
Building and running apjsua sample application

We have apjsua sample application located under `pjsip-apps/src/apjsua`. It is not built by default, and you need `SWIG` to build it.

Follow these steps to build apjsua:

> Make sure SWIG is in the build environment PATH. Alternatively, update
>   SWIG path in $PJDIR/pjsip-apps/src/apjsua/jni/Android.mk file. Run
>   ndk-build from directory $PJDIR/pjsip-apps/src/apjsua, note that the
>   Android NDK root should be in the PATH, e.g:
>
> Create Android project from apjsua. In Eclipse: From menu: File -->
>   New --> Project Select Android Project from Existing Code, press Next
>   In Root Directory, put the location of apjsua source code (i.e.
>   $PJDIR/pjsip-apps/src/apjsua) and press Finish You may need to select
>   different Android SDK than what is configured in apjsua. You can do
>   this from the project's Properties. You can modify
>   apjsua/res/raw/config.txt for apjsua's config file. Run it.

My question is :
How to use swig? I am very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about swig. You should compile it, and add it to the environment path.
ndk-build will call swig application. You can add it to the PATH by typing in terminal 
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/swig , where /path/to/swig is location on your computer of swig app.